# Book on set theory counterexamples

Tags: elementary-set-theory, book-recommendation

Could anyone suggest a book which would be the equivalent of "Counterexamples in Analysis" for set theory? That is to say, I am looking for a book which would elaborate on the important examples and misconceptions in set theory.
Per say, an example of poset which is lattice and but not complete, etc.

Comment: Actually, proposing or trying to find counterexamples is worthwhile in helping you learn elementary set theory, and to anticipate what's you'll find down the road.  It's a good way to approach your studies: Examples in which elementary set theory displays important aspects of theorems, but also, examining the counterexamples which help in realizing the limits of those theorems... The "Counterexamples in ... " series didn't take on set theory, but there is a book on Counterexamples in Topology, which may be of some use.

Comment: Thanks, I will look through that book.

Comment: Take a look at the [Wikipedia entry on "Naive Set Theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory).  It gives an overview of its history, and paradoxes revealed, which were dealt with in axiomatic systems...Naive set theory doesn't mean "not real" set theory. It is a more like elementary set theory, and more advanced forms of set theory.  The entry does show paradoxes (counterexample) led to more and more sophisticated axioms;  when you scroll towards the bottom of the entry, there is a subjection on paradoxes, and at the bottom of the entry, you'll find some good references.